# how to use vue.js offline?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuejs3

Hi I received a web project with all already implemented CSS js HTML code, directories, project structure etc.

I have to make changes in view.js but I don’t always have internet access on the move so is there a way to continue this project locally without changing my project structure?

I already have an existing web project whose file contains
-an HTML page
-a CSS file
-a js file
Place in their folders respectively

I want to use view.js on this project
The problem I don’t always have internet access when I’m on the move.
So how do I use seen?

Knowing that:

- CDN is a script placed in HTML requiring a connection to run view

-Vue CLI is a package that allows to generate a new project view "certainly out of competition"
But I should start over
Because the directory structure and already predefined what doesn’t suit me.

How does it work?

How to just add view and continue the project without zero spread?

I already installed node.js (npm) on my pc if its can help .

"-- IN BRIEF:
If you still don’t understand
Imagine being entrusted with a web project all made HTML CSS JS already configure etc...
And you must use VUE to make changes
knowing that on the move you don’t always have the connection

How do you do that?

Comment: Hi, please cut 75% of your question here and keep only the relevant pieces please. Can't you start a new Vue project and use NPM packages to have everything locally? Far more context + effort is required from your side here.

Comment: Some other solutions like caching with a PWA are also totally feasible but we will not get into those as this stage for sure.

Comment: It's unclear how Vue app and the rest of the project are related. The usual way to use Vue is SPA. You won't be able to efficiently communicate between Vue and non-Vue scripts, so the problem is primarily that you see this from the wrong point of view. Vue is commonly used with Vue CLI or Vite setups that forces you to use their structure. Otherwise you're on your own, whatever you'll see in tutorials and code examples won't be applicable. It's possible to use Vue in so-called CDN mode, basically load Vue script on HTML page and use `Vue` global. If it's saved locally then can be used offline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming (I can't tell 100% from your description) that it is an un-compiled implementation that uses the CDN, you can easily handle this by copying the vue library locally and update the html to use the local version instead of the CDN.

if you need to keep the html, you could use a browser plugin like [requestly](https://requestly.io/) but there are many others. There you can select the url that goes to the cdn and replace it with the local one.

Another option for chromium-based browsers is to use local overrides. Picture upload is not working currently, so can't include a picture, but the option is available through the sources tab in the developer tools. You need to enable overrides, select a folder, then you can select the resource that you want to serve from local override.

Comment: Wasn't aware of requestedly, looks like a good tool, thanks

Comment: it's freemium though‍♂️ and limits the number of requests. It's really easy to make your own plugin though, most of the complexity is in the UI.